# VNC, How can I connect to my Mac with RealVNC, it works with TighVNC, connection aborted 10053?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, vnc, realvnc, tightvnc

I'm trying to connect to my Mac Mini (its running Snow Leopard) from my Windows XP Laptop.

I've managed it with no problem and no changes to any of the settings with TightVNC.

In RealVNC, I've entered my mac IP address and entered the correct password.

But I get the Error...

Title: `VNC Viewer : Question`

Message: `read: Connection aborted (10053)
Do you wish to attempt to reconnect to 192.168.7.12?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the color settings to Full.

Comment: Great! In Remmina VNC client this is called 24 bit colors

Answer (score 1):

The message can also be:

```
message **write**: connection aborted (10053) ....
```

The solution is the same: in tab colours/encoding, select **Full (all available colours)**.

Optionally: in tab load/save, click "save" (default) profile, unless you want to do this every time.

I tested this with VNCviewer 4.1.3 against Mac OS X Server 10.6.8.